# Verification of 555 timer design

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, 555

[image: Schematic]

I have designed a circuit that can turn on and off any load connected with constant delay based on the potentiometer reading. It is based on GreatScott's design. Can anyone verify this design and point out the errors and improvements.
I'm not sure whether this design will work. So help me out!
[image: PCB]

Layout edit 2:
[image]

Comment: For a simple circuit like this, you should breadboard it to verify the design.

Comment: I am afraid nobody is going to verify your design, unless you debug it yourself on board and come back with a specific problem.

Comment: You should have a bypass capacitor across the supply. That is especially important if you are using a bipolar 555. C2 and C3 footprint and value are not congruent. 470uF would be polarized and larger. C3 does not normally need to be larger than 100nF.

Comment: Mattman944 I am new to the forum. i will learn by my mistakes.

Comment: Spehro Pefhany, what do you mean by congruent? Do you mean the values?
I have changed my C3 value as per your suggestion. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with James and all the comments in the post + I would like to add something to the PCB design.

- It is good practice not to use 90°/acute angles on the traces. It can make problems when etching the PCB and it does not look good :)
- It is a 2 layer board right? For your GND make a ground plane instead. It improves the signal integrity.
- Make your power traces thicker then signal traces. Looking at your design, I would make all traces thicker.
- Consider mounting holes. If your design work, you may need a way how to use the PCB in your project without duct tape.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pulse width modulator and, looking at the circuit diagram, the basic circuit topology looks ok to me.

One problem - If the pot is wound right to either end then there will be no resistance between the 555's output (pin3) and the capacitor and so when the output switches one way it will have to supply a very large current to try and charge the capacitor almost instantaneously.

Solution 1 - Add a resistor in series with the pot at either end of it.

Solution 2 - Add a single resistor in that short connection between the point where THR and TR are connected and the connection between the two diodes.

The effect of adding the resistor(s) will be to put a max and min limit on the duty cycle.

I can't understand why C3 has such a large value (470uF). Normally the CV pin would be decoupled to ground with a 10n capacitor.

Comment: I have changed tha value of C3 to 10nf cap. I have added the resistors in all places required

Comment: I couldn't find a way to add images in the comment so edited my question and added the layout

Comment: @Pranesh You have changed the value of C2, it's C3 that needs changing to 10nF (103). My answer was supposed to imply that either my Solution 1 or my Solution 2 was required, not both. In any case you've put R3 in the wrong position. So, either delete R3 and put R4 the other side of the diode for tideness or delete R2 & R4 and move R3 to the correct position which I specified in Solution 2. THR and TR should be shorted together. It's not rocket salad!

Comment: I am just 15 and I am practising tyo design pcb's. I have edited my design now